# Excel file upload/import using cypress

Tags: automation, cypress

I've a UI similar to
[image]

I need to upload a xlsx file which I have placed in fixture folder in to the application. Any suggestions how to do it using cypress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what I found as the solution

1. Install cypress-file-upload

   npm install --save-dev cypress-file-upload
2. Add following to command .js file

   import 'cypress-file-upload';
3. Use cy.attachFile

const yourFixturePath = 'data.json';
 cy.get('[data-cy="file-input"]').attachFile(yourFixturePath);

For details
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload