# I am using cypress to automate. I need to open the window file upload dialog and attach any file. How can I do it?

Tags: typescript, cypress

the selector of the button is [data-ele="no-logo-ele"]

cy.get('[data-ele="no-logo-ele"]').click();

This code does not do anything. Do I have to install any dependency for this?

Comment: Yes you need to add install cypress-file-upload. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62206500/excel-file-upload-import-using-cypress. This gives basics of what you can do!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel file upload/import using cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62206500/excel-file-upload-import-using-cypress)

Comment: The code that you have doesn't do anything because Cypress only controls the browser and can't control interactions with the computer's file system.